# I ran a code to link my computer to another one using the 22 nd port. But not receiving any data

Tags: python, sockets

This is my code i run on LeafPad in Linux
when i run this code and trying to see data in 'sample' variable of my program I'm not getting the output just a blank terminal only. How i get the output for this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import socket
practice = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) #TCP


#port 22 (iam are trying to connect with port 22 of the server)
practice.connect(("192.168.1.107",22))
 
socket.send('GET HTTP/1.1 \r\n')

sample = practice.recv(1024)
print(sample)

practice.close()
```

Comment: i tried socket.send() but it says no attribute named send

Comment: yes, i have edited the snippet now..